# How do I validate a textfield to only show 2 kinds of text

Tags: ios, textfield

In iOS, whats the best way to validate a textfield to make sure that the text field has a certain text in it?

I have

```
    TaxiOrCust.text
```

and I only want the words `Customer` or `Taxi` In the text field. the words must have the first letter in Uppercase.

Is there a way to validate this in Xcode?

Comment: Why don't you try the `UIPickerView` instead ?

Comment: do you want to let user type only those two words? and rest should be cleared out (but when do you want to delete it?)

Comment: Using a `UITExtField` is not a good choice if the user can only enter (pick) one of two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you REALLY shouldn't be using a textfield if the user is only allowed to enter two very specific things, but rather a picker or something similar. BUT, if that is REALLY what you want to do for some other reason, the following code does just that:

```
if ([TaxiOrCust.text isEqualToString:@"Customer"]) {
    NSLog(@"User entered 'Customer' with a capital C.");
}
else if ([TaxiOrCust.text isEqualToString:@"Taxi"]) {
    NSLog(@"User entered 'Taxi' with a capital T.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"The user has entered an incorrect value.");
}
```

Comment: yea i perhaps may do a picker view but I've never done one before  but first time for everything